# weird behaviour in css transform:rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i trying to make this item `draggable and rotatable.`

however if i set `transform:rotate(0deg);`
i can drag everywhere in the parent container.
but if i set it to `90deg.` there are some area became `undraggable` and it extended out of the parent container as well.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="myitem"><p>my rotate/drag</p></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{   
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:red;
}

#myitem{
width:115px;
height 50px;
background:black;
transform-origin:top left;
transform: rotate("90deg);
 -ms-transform-origin:top left;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin:top left;
}
```

look for the example here
[click here for sample of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/learningweb/28WG3/15/)

> Have solucioned the problem!

If capture `$(foo).offset().left` when set css scale the value is not equals to real position if use `transform-origin: top left;`

To fix this replace 
`$(foo).offset().left by parseInt($(foo).css('left').replace('px',))` 
but need set
 `position after run: foo{ top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; }`

:)

The problem is who detect `transform-origin` and difference of positions when apply an `scale().` Calculate by `%`?

Comment: This issue has been reported to jquery and set to 'wontfix', there is a user submitted solution on this page - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6844

Comment: It is because transform behaves like position:relative; the element is rotated at screen but still uses and remains in its original area, shape . Give it absolute positionning and go even more nuts :) http://jsfiddle.net/28WG3/16/

Comment: rubo123.
u means solution by zkizzik?
i dont really understand what he is  trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just running around your question, basically you want a draggable and rotatable with container...

I have done some changes to your fiddle and try to achieve this, http://jsfiddle.net/28WG3/19/

Some changes to the html too:-

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main"><div id="myitem"><p>my rotate/drag</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this works for you...

Comment: hi this is what i actually wants. but myitem size always change therefor i need some dynamic codes. is ok. i will try that out using ur logics.

thanks